# WSO2 stream processor unable to save file to workspace

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I installed WSO2 Stream Processor on ubuntu server.
Then started the editor and accessed to Stream Processor Studio from another PC through browser.
I am unable to save a file to workspace ("Error in reading the file location undefined")
What's wrong ? Did I made a mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Support for accessing remote filesystem had been blocked in v4.1.0 since Product SP was using a custom file import. This has been fixed by integrating with OS native file browser in [#565](https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/pull/565). The fix is available with [v4.2.0-rc1](https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/releases/tag/v4.2.0-rc1).

Product SP 4.2.0 will be released by the end of this month.